# Probability and condition

Tags: probability

I have a simple problem where I am getting 2 different results.

Its given that
$P(A) = 0.22, \;P(B) = 0.35,\; P(A \cup B) = 0.54$

Now using below method

$P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = P(A \cup B)$

$0.22 + 0.35 - P(A \cap B) = 0.54$

$P(A \cap B) = 0.03$

---

Now using a simple method

$P(A) \cdot P(B) = P(A \cap B)$

$P(A \cap B) = 0.077$

Can someone explain where my understanding is incorrect?

Comment: the second equality $P(A)P(B)=P(A\cap B) $ holds iff $A$ and $B$ are independenly. You just showed thati this is not the case

Comment: If e.g. $A\subseteq B$ then $P(A\cap B)=P(A)=0.22$. As @ALG says: the equality $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ states that $A$ and $B$ are independent events, which is not always the case.

Comment: @ALG can you please explain how do did you infer from above that 2 events are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

The "simple method" is clearly incorrect, as the independence of $A$ and $B$, an assumption the method makes, has not been established beforehand. Therefore it cannot be applied at all, and the Venn diagram approach has to be employed instead.

By deriving $P(A\cap B)$ through this correct approach, we do show that $A$ and $B$ are not independent, but that is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Its not clear how the probabilities given shows that they are not independent event. Can you please explain ? how its intuitive to you ?

Comment: can you please elaborate as i do not understand.